# Not caching value of for loop

Tags: vb.net

When doing a for loop, the value after the To is being cached.

```
    Dim m As Integer = 1

    For x As Integer = 0 To m
        Console.WriteLine(x)
        m = 10
    Next
```

Output is

```
    0
    1
```

Is there a way to not cache the value m ? The only way I could solve it was to convert the For into a While loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to make it evaluate more than once.  From the [`For..Next` Statement Documentation (Visual Basic) (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/5z06z1kb.aspx)

```
For counter [ As datatype ] = start To end [ Step step ]
    [ statements ]
    [ Continue For ]
    [ statements ]
    [ Exit For ]
    [ statements ]
Next [ counter ]
```

> When a `For`...`Next` loop starts, Visual Basic evaluates start, end, and step. **Visual Basic evaluates these values only at this time.**